# How to customize flex tree icon programatically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tree, icons, flex-mx

I can modify the icons of mx.controls.Tree component using setStyle

```
tree.setStyle("disclosureOpenIcon",myIcon1);
tree.setStyle("disclosureClosedIcon",myIcon2);
tree.setStyle("folderClosedIcon",myIcon3);
tree.setStyle("folderOpenIcon",myIcon4);
tree.setStyle("defaultLeafIcon",myIcon5);
```

Where myIconx is of class "Class" which is embedded  images.
But i need to customize the icons in a way that icons should be drawn using actionscript, we can use a component extended   from sprite/uicomponent for showing an actionscript drawing. But how we can use that as a tree icon?

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom item renderer, read documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/treeClasses/TreeItemRenderer.html  ,